# Python3 DictWriter using CRLF instead of LF on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

**Problem:**

In Python 3, I'm using csv.DictWriter to append a row to an existing file. However, CRLF line endings are being used instead of the expected LF line endings.

**Code example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv

with open("test.csv", 'a', newline='') as test_f:
    test_csv = csv.DictWriter(test_f, delimiter='|', fieldnames=['1', '2'])
    test_csv.writerow({'1': "test1", '2': "test2"})
```

**Expected result:**

```
$ cat -e test.csv
test1|test2$
```

**Actual result:**

```
$ cat -e test.csv
test1|test2^M$
```

**Notes:**

- The existing file's fileformat is "unix", not "dos".
- I have tried setting [newline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to None (the default) and '\n' as well (even that should be unnecessary since the default value is os.linedep, which is already '\n' on Linux), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By specifying [`lineterminator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator), you can control it.

```
test_csv = csv.DictWriter(
    test_f,
    delimiter='|',
    lineterminator='\n',  # <--------
    fieldnames=['1', '2'])
```